# Convert from a sequence diagram to collaboration diagram

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, uml

I know that I can convert a sequence diagram into a collaboration diagram easily using Rational Rose, but... Using Visual Studio, that is possible? Or I will have to create by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no support for collaboration diagram conversion in Visual Studio.

Comment: yeah! you are right, that is a pitty It had to be done by myself.